# Does a Mace of Disruption's Frightened effect override some undead's immunity to the Frightened condition?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, weapons, immunities, fear

The description of the [Mace of Disruption](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/mace-of-disruption) states:

> When you hit a fiend or an undead with this magic weapon [...] If the target has 25 hit points or fewer after taking this damage, it must succeed on a DC 15 Wisdom saving throw or be destroyed. On a successful save, **the creature becomes frightened of you until the end of your next turn**.

Some undead are immune to the Frightened condition. Does the Mace override that immunity? Or does it only cause Frightened in those undead which are not immune to the condition?

Comment: Related: [Can undead be frightened?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/78479/can-undead-be-frightened) and [Can a Mace of Disruption kill a Vampire with its ability?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/119165/can-a-mace-of-disruption-kill-a-vampire-with-its-ability)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

## Immunity to Frightened condition prevails

The mace doesn't say anything about ignoring condition immunities, so it doesn't. Any undead that is immune to the condition is not affected by the mace in this way.